# Load Navigation Property by its Key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, entity-relationship, asp.net-mvc-validation

I am using the EF CF approach and have:

the following data model:

```
public class Category {
    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
public class Product {
    [Key]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

the following DataContect definition:

```
public class EFCFContext : DbContext {
    public EFCFContext() : base("EFCFConnection") { }

    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

The purpose of this code is as follows:

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application. There is a form for editing the Product entity, and a "lookup" selector/editor for the Category entity bound with the Category.CategoryID property.

When submitting the form to the corresponding HttpPost Action, the Product.Category.CategoryName is still empty. I do not have a direct instance of the Category object in this scope:

```
//Category cat = new Category();
//cat.CategoryName = "Fake Name";
//context.Categories.Add(cat);
//context.SaveChanges();

EFCFContext context = new EFCFContext();

Product prod = new Product();
prod.ProductName = "Fake Name";
prod.Category = new Category();
prod.Category.CategoryID = cat.CategoryID;

//prod.Category.CategoryName is null. ModelState Error is added.

context.SaveChanges();
```

As a result, some Model Validation errors occur.
I need to assign/reload the Product's Category property explicitly, since I already know the CategoryID.

So my question is:

How do I force the navigation property to load by its Key/ID without the extra steps (and thus avoid the ModelState Errors)?

I may be going in the wrong direction. Any guidance will be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with the "*extra step*" that you want to avoid, but it seems to me that you just need to replace the 2 lines `prod.Category = new Category(); prod.Category.CategoryID = cat.CategoryID;` by the line `prod.Category = context.Categories.Find(cat.CategoryID);`. You can also add a `public int CategoryID { get; set; }` FK property to `Product` and bind your selector to `Product.CategoryID` instead of `Product.Category.CategoryID` to avoid the whole procedure to reload the category. But somehow I have the feeling I misunderstand the question...

Comment: Extra information would be most helpful. Can you show your action signature and the form that is posting to it?